# Unable to unlock pattern in Android Marshmallow on notification arrival

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-6.0-marshmallow, keyguard

I am trying to unlock screen as soon as notification arrives . I have applied this code (tried 2 code snippet) but none of them is working for android marshmallow and working fine for lollipop .

Code snippet 1:

```
KeyguardManager km = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(GCMNotificationIntentService.KEYGUARD_SERVICE); 
            final KeyguardManager.KeyguardLock kl = km .newKeyguardLock(KEYGUARD_SERVICE); 
            kl.disableKeyguard();
```

Code snippet 2:

```
KeyguardManager km = (KeyguardManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
            KeyguardLock keyguardLock = km.newKeyguardLock("TAG");
            ((Activity) mContext).getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
            ((Activity) mContext).getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);

            keyguardLock.disableKeyguard();
```

Comment: Do you find the solution. I am having the same issue

Comment: @user8430  getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD |
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED |
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON |
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON 
    );

Comment: Because I am in service. I cannot use the function getWindow().

Comment: Same here. What I did was opened a class from Service and put this code in onCreate

Comment: So you will call an acitivity, and then call above function. After that, you call finish(). Is it right?

Comment: I am using Service to send Notification. So after sending notification ,I am calling another activity .